# Error: Permission denied to access property 'category'

Tags: javascript, console, runtime-error, firebug

I cannot figure out why I'm getting the below console error in Firefox 34 with Firebug 2.0.7. This is a simple block of code. It works fine in Safari, Chrome and IE.

> **"Error: Permission denied to access property 'category' myscript.js (line 7)"**

```
var MyMaterials = function() {
var category, material;
return console.dir(this);
}

record_1 = new MyMaterials;
record_1.category = "Clear Film";
record_1.material = "Opticlear PC 5000";

console.log(record_1.category);
console.log(record_1.material);
```

Comment: Why are you returning console.dir(this) ? I have tested it in firefox 32,34 and 36 and is working ok. Maybe the issue is with your firebug version and the console.dir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple. Stop returning `console.dir(this)`.

When you return a non-primitive in a constructor, you get that value instead of the object instance. `console.dir` returns some other object that is not the object instance and throws this error, at least in Firebug anyway, the native developer tools don't seem to have this issue.

**Fixed code:**

```
var MyMaterials = function() {
var category, material;
console.dir(this);
}

record_1 = new MyMaterials;
record_1.category = "Clear Film";
record_1.material = "Opticlear PC 5000";

console.log(record_1.category);
console.log(record_1.material);
```